# cw complex inclusion induces homotopy group isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, he proved the following result:
For a path-connected CW complex $X$ the inclusion $X^1 \rightarrow X$ induces a surjection on $\pi_1$, and the inclusion $X^2 \rightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$. I am wondering whether there is an analogous result to higher homotopy group.

Comment: Yes. See Corollary 4.12.

Comment: @Tyrone You should give an official answer to clear the question from the "unanswered" queue.